# Connect to CentOS desktop (GUI) installed on Google cloud

Tags: user-interface, google-cloud-platform, centos7, remote-desktop, vnc-server

I've installed Centos7 on the Google Cloud Platform, as you know there is just ssh option to connect to the machine.
Now I need to have access to its desktop(GUI) from my laptop (it's win10).
it's appreciated if anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to ssh login into your CentOS machine either from ssh button in Gcloud, or using the cloud shell:

```
gcloud compute ssh test-vws
```

then setup a password for your account:

```
sudo passwd `whoami`
```

After that, you will need to install a client that will allow you to navigate the GUI for your server.

again, on your server command line execute:

```
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y groupinstall 'Server with GUI'
```

once finished, follow this guige to install and setup Teradici Cloud Access Software (Remote Desktop Agent for CentOS).

[Installing Teradici Cloud Access Software](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/creating-a-virtual-linux-workstation#installing_teradici_cloud_access_software)

1. On your virtual workstation, install the Teradici repositories:

```
sudo yum -y install https://downloads.teradici.com/rhel/teradici-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

2. Install Teradici Standard Agent for Linux:

```
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y install pcoip-agent-standard
```

Then you will have to register the Agent and create a firewall rule to allow the connection, just follow the guide, and your desktop connection will look like this:

[image]